# apt-get does not install any programs or update after upgrade from 11.04 to 14.04 (LTS)

Tags: apt, upgrade, 14.04, package-management

I've upgraded from 11.04 to 14.04 and I have some issues when using `apt-get`.

Below is an example of what I get when trying to install `mysql-server` (same issue for any package installation):

```
~$: sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mountall : Breaks: initscripts (< 2.88dsf-24)
            Breaks: initscripts:i386 (< 2.88dsf-24)
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Here is a an output of `sudo apt-get install -f` posted on [paste bin](http://pastebin.com/Mxvsu1eZ). I've also done `apt-get remove`, `clean` `purge` and `autoremove` which seems no luck.

How can I get this fixed?

## EDIT

Here is the result of `apt-cache policy initscripts`

```
~$ apt-cache policy initscripts
initscripts:
  Installed: 2.88dsf-13.10ubuntu11.1
  Candidate: 2.88dsf-41ubuntu6
  Version table:
     2.88dsf-41ubuntu6 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.88dsf-13.10ubuntu11.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Can you run `apt-cache policy initscripts` and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/462066/edit) your question and paste the output there?

Comment: @saiarcot895 added paste

Comment: Can you try `sudo apt-get upgrade`? Is it the same result?

Comment: Can you also explain the nature of your upgrade?? Because **AFAIK**, officially it is not possible for you to go from 11.04 to 14.04 directly.

Answer (score 0):

Is it going good to uninstall and install initscripts package? It means,

```
apt-get uninstall initscripts
apt-get install initscripts
```

Or, you can rebuild file database shown in

```
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1776763
```

I hope this answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're still on Ubuntu 11.04. As [AzkerM](https://askubuntu.com/users/179042/azkerm) commented, officially it is not possible for you to go from 11.04 to 14.04 directly.

Ubuntu 11.04 is now on "End of Life" and is not supported anymore...that's the reason why your installations via **apt-get** goes with no success.

You may refer to this [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) for the list of [Releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) that are still supported.